# Google Maps Geocoding API Incorrect Rate Limiting

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary

I'm adding a mapping function to one of the internal tools used by my company.  Long story short, we have a list of about 50 addresses that need to be placed on a map.  I'm using Google Maps so that it is an interactive map, and then the javascript API for geocoding and adding the markers.

According to [Google's documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/faq.html#usage_limits), I am limitted to 10 requests per second.  So, I've set my javascript to churn through an array of addresses, and put a delay in between each batch.

So my function is setup with two confif variables that I can set: addressesPerBatch and timeoutPerBatch - pretty obvious what each one should do.  You would think that, judging from Google's documentation, I would be allowed

```
 addressesPerBatch = 10;
 timeoutPerBatch = 1000; //That's in milliseconds
```

I am most certainly not.  I very quickly hit my rate limit when I send requests that quickly.  The sweet spot that I've found is actually around"

```
 addressesPerBatch = 2;
 timeoutPerBatch = 2000;
```

So, is this a problem with my javascript, or a problem with Google's rate limiting?

I've created a jsfiddle so you can get a better idea of exactly what I'm doing:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qt4gV/1/

Comment: How about adding a sleep/retry only when you hit OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, so you don't have to try and tweak your configuration to match the API limits exactly.

Comment: @ScottWegner That is actually a [suggested method by google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html#geocodephp).  I've considered doing that (and probably will), but it still doesn't answer the root problem.  I *should* be allowed 10 requests per second, but right now I'm only getting 1 per second.

Comment: The rate limit documentation you cite above is specific to "Google Maps API Premier".  The general usage limits described here don't quote a specific per-minute limit: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#usagelimits. Note that since you're making the calls as client-side javascript, the quotas apply against the client. This is beneficial for you, except if the user is behind a proxy where many clients are hitting the same quota: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geocodestrat.html#quota-limits

Comment: @ScottWegner "There is also a rate limit of 10 requests per second that **applies to all Google Maps API Web Services.**"

Comment: @jwegner – that's still on the premier page, so it only would apply to premier customers (I think it's saying you can do 100 000 geocodes a day, but you can't do that all within one second!) This page says the limit for free geocodes is 2500 per day which is less than 0.3 per second. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer to a similar question on the Google code page: "The Geocoding API request rate limit is not to be disclosed to help minimize service abuse."
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3099#c4

Like what @jwegner mentioned in the comments, one should check the returned status code and implement constant backoff for the case "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".

Answer (score 0):

When I was doing large batches of geocoding, I did it serially with a timeout of about 0.25 seconds between each query. This didn't cause problems and was still fast enough. The DB updates too far longer than the request/response of the geocoding.

Also, if you have a Premier license make sure you follow the directions about adding a signature to the request or your requests will be treated like you were using the free license. I learned this the hard way when I maxed out my daily limit with  few test run on my development server!