# Google Maps Query_Limit_Reached?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been writing some code with Google Maps, and trying to take in a (I won't lie) fairly large amount of data with the Places Library. I know that each search returns up to 20 points. In my JavaScript application, I make 625 calls to the search over a fairly small area. However, there are so many duplicates that I feel like I am in not even making more than 100 markers on the map in my search. Anyway, I used to see ~74 results, but now I only see 40 and see that many of my searches just don't happen because of some OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status that is returned when I try to run a place search. Is there some reason why? I know for a fact that the accesses to the website number less than 10 in a day.

The main driver for my search is like this:

function mapSearch() {
    $.each(pointArray, function(i, iArray) {
        $.each(iArray, function(j, point) {
            placeRequest(pointArray[i][j]);
        });
    });
}

Comment: There is a reason, probably that you are running too quickly. But there's not enough information here (like a link, or the relevant bit of code) to say exactly what the reason is.

Comment: It appears that you're using the Places API in a very unconventional way and against the intended use case for the API.  Why are you making so many calls for a small area?

Comment: I am trying to find all of the establishments in an area, and each place search only gives up to 20 points because that's how it's set up with google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pay for Google Maps API for Business your rate is limited to 10 transactions per second. I wouldn't expect non-paying users to get any better rates. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq?hl=en#usage_limits

There's some discussion at [Google Maps Geocoding API Incorrect Rate Limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955899/google-maps-geocoding-api-incorrect-rate-limiting) on how to live with this.